# Skype auto link

Tags: navigation

I know how to add a link field in Drupal for Skype (skype:username?chat), but I dind't find any answer about automatically convert it into a Skype link. 
Let's say users fill their profiles and in a link field write "foreigner"; this link should be automatically converted into `<a href="skype:foreigner?chat">foreigner</a>` when shown.

How can I achieve this task?

I'm using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module I would use is the [Skype Status](https://drupal.org/project/skype_status) module. Despite the name, it shows a link to allow users to chat or call another user on Skype.

> Retrieves Skype status information via Skype's public presence service for users to display in their profile and also provides a block for site-wide usage (available only in D7!).

What you need to do is:

- Install and enable the Skype Status module
- Add a user profile where users can enter their Skype ID
- Go to admin/config/people/skype_status

  - Select the field used for the Skype ID
  - Change the action performed when the button is clicked
  - Select the button style

[image: screenshot]

Once the users enter their Skype ID, their user profile will show a button to chat/call them, which shows also their status on Skype.

[image: screenshot]

For the status to be visible, users need to select "Shows my status on the web" for their Skype account from the Skype application.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Ok, I'll try that module. Thank you very much! I'll tweak the images that comes with the module, to create what I want to look like.